# Smartphone to smartphone communication - what are the options?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, nat-traversal

I developed an iPhone game and I want to add multiplayer capabilities.
In order to do that I whould need bi-directional connection between the iphones during the game.
I did a little research at google and came out with the following options:

1. Getting a virtual private server or dedicated machin out there in the cloud and implement a server that will replay the communication between the devices (later on, a more sophisticated nat traversal technic can be used).
   The adventage:
   A. Not tying myself to specific smartphone׳s platform.
   B. The server can handle some of the logics.
   C. Implementation of more feathers such as statistics and advanced logging can be added.
   The disadvantages:
   A. Developing another software - the server.
   B. paying a lot for the server hosting (80$ - 500$ per month).
   C. Taking care of server security and maintaining the server.
2. Use the Apple game center.
   The advantage:
   A. Simple and fast. (Using game-kit)
   B. free (or low cost? I couldn't find any reference for that)
   The disadvantage:
   A. I can use only the feathers that game center supplies.
   B. I wouldn't be able to make my game cross-platform. (What did "Clash of clans" developers did?)

Is there another option?
I looked for a service that is Game Center like but cross-platform and couldn't found.

Did I miss advantage/disadvantage?

Comment: Clash of Clans almost definitely has it sown servers- and many of them.

Answer (score 1):

Nice search you made...I think make use of bluetooth if there is small distance, of if you can use micro controller based RF transmission using hardware attached to you iphone

Comment: We are talking long distances here... Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

if local connection over wifi is an option, you should look at Apple's samplecode [WiTap](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html)